# How to generate typings for css in rollup

Tags: css, typescript, typescript-typings, rollup

I am using **rollup** as my module builder and **Typescript** in my source. Now, I need to define some CSS files for my module. 
On importing my CSS file to the `.ts` file I get the following error
    `Cannot find module './styles.css'.`
How do I generate typings for my CSS files?

I came across an npm package [typed-css-modules](https://github.com/Quramy/typed-css-modules) to generate the typings. I tried using it but again my CSS classes do not get exported to my `.ts` file.

Comment: did you try `import './styles.css';` ?

Comment: yeah, I tried importing directly, but I am not able to use the CSS classes.

Comment: how about `require('./styles.css');`?

Comment: I tried that too it's not working. And, in this case, the generated CSS file is empty.

Comment: Maybe you have syntax errors in your css file?

Comment: Here are the contents of my CSS file. `.btn { color: green; }`. @Roysh

Comment: well, the only thing i can think of is that you may not importing the css file from the right path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyways, I found the solution to my problem.
I am now using this package to generate Typings

[rollup-plugin-postcss-modules](https://github.com/flying-sheep/rollup-plugin-postcss-modules)